# How to check whether http header is present

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, coldfusion-7

How can I check whether Accept-Language header is present in request?
I've tried this, but it produces an error

```
<cfset requestData = GetHttpRequestData() >
<cfif IsDefined("requestData.Headers['Accept-Language']")>
...
```

Sorry for probably lame question. That's my first day of ColdFusion coding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

isDefined() is very limited in it's usage, so you can't use associative array notation with it. In almost every case you're better off using StructKeyExists() anyway. So, to solve your problem:

use:
   `<cfif StructKeyExists( RequestData.Headers, "Accept-Language" )>`